# Local variables in Stack -> C

Tags: c, stack

How can I find the difference between the position of two local variables in Stack?

I have a function and then I have to add a local variable to the stack. Then I must find the difference between that local variable and the first argument of the function.

Comment: Take the difference of their addresses cast to `char const *`? But that's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why? Is there some larger problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: this is just a exercise I have to do, but can't figured out how to..

Comment: The first argument of the function might not even *be* on the stack. Compiler optimizations, calling conventions, all that.

Comment: @DCoder is correct. On x86, with the Cdecl calling convention, all parameters *should* be on the stack, but not on x86_64. Throw in another architecture like ARM, and you're in a huge situation to wade through.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "stack" in C, and what you propose isn't possible by the rules of the language. You can try and employ the following construction, which may do what you want, but know that it has undefined behaviour:

```
void foo(int arg)
{
  double x;

  ptrdiff_t diff = (char const *)(&x) - (char const *)(&arg);
  printf("Difference between %p and %p: %td\n", (void*)(&x), (void*)(&arg), diff);
}
```

The output depends on the details of your implementation. It may be easier to look a tthe generated machine code to get this information.

(The code has undefined behaviour because it pretends that all the variables live inside some large `char` array, which they don't.)

Comment: Why aren't you using `ptrdiff_t`?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: I didn't remember the printf macro for it :-)

Comment: That would be `%tu` (or `%tx`): http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Integer-Conversions.html

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Great, thanks! I was looking for a `inttypes.h` macro, but in fact there's a conversion specifier for it. Neat.